# How to change the contact info at the bottom of my theme

Tags: themes, contact

Im currently using the Spina theme for my website and at the bottom of the page above the footer it has a section with the headings "contact us", "receent posts"(It's actually misspelled like that), "meta", and "tags". The contact us section displays info that I have never entered. Like for the email it lists youremail@gmail.com. Iv tried but I cant figure out how to edit any of this information.

Comment: The theme's author should be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This theme downloads 2 folders with name `kyma` and `spina`.
so, go to `kyma\functions\customize` where you get `contact-widgets.php` and change `contact` information there.

Answer (score 1):

Spina is a child theme of Kyma theme. And what you are seeing is the 'footer sidebar' with several widgets defined in the **footer.php** in Kyma theme. But, they are displayed only if you don't add widgets into **Footer Widgets** sidebar area in WordPress Admin -> Appearance -> Widgets.

If you don't want this area at all, you can edit **footer.php** are remove it altogether. You can copy footer.php from Kyma to Spina and edit it in Spina folder.